# What is new-breakpoint second argument for?

Tags: sass, bourbon, neat

Im trying to learn bourbon-neat, came across its breakpoint feature that takes a query and grid-columns. What is the use of grid-columns there? Why would you set the grid-columns like that when you can change the columns on the fly with declaration to span-columns?

Just need abit more explanation as to why you will provide a second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It is just to provide a little more flexibility. You may never use it, but for instance you may wish to have a 12 column grid for large screens and a 5 column grid for smaller columns. In this instance span-columns would not work as 12 cannot be divided by 5.

Admittedly you may not use it that often!

Comment: could you provide an example for use case for I might need it, i just dont like understanding things

Comment: Example would be a site with a sidebar and main content. 

On larger screens you could have a sidebar of 4 of 12 columns, and a main content section of 8 of 12 columns (1:2 ratio).

Then on smaller screens you could have a sidebar of 2 of 5 columns, and a main content section of 3 of 5 columns (2:3 ratio). You can't achieve a 2:3 ratio with a 12 column grid, hence custom grid-columns